# How do I reference images in my S3 bucket from local dev app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

Please see: [On Amazon S3 I'm able to give an individual object download rights but cannot for the entire bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763031/on-amazon-s3-im-able-to-give-an-individual-object-download-rights-but-cannot-fo) for the next evolution of this question.

I've got a bucket with all my images uploaded.  I'm trying to access them via their url as instructed by https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3.  I of course want to make sure I can access them before I upload my latest changes to my live app.  I've got the yml set up appropriately as far as I can tell, but the images are not loading when I visit the site running locally on WEBRICK.  I have not made any changes to the AWS files in my rubygems directory.  Here's an example of the reference I'm using to display the image:

```
<%= image_tag("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/someimage.jpg") %>
```

Can anyone provide me with some instructions?  I know there are instructions for adding code to the included AWS files, but I cannot understand them enough to go in there and monkey around.  Thanks.

I added the following to my bucket policy:

```
{
  "Id": "somepolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "someid",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myapp/mykey",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am still unable to access the images.  Is `GetObject` the appropriate action to allow?

Comment: What happens if you just follow the image url? Does the image load?

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie, I get access denied.  I'm not sure if that's an adequate test because I'm never putting in the credentials in my browser.  You did prompt me to check the url in S3 and it is actually `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/someimage.jpg'

Comment: That is your problem... You seem to only allow requests from specific domains so no requests will work in development.

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie, I changed the permissions to everyone - view permissions and I still get access denied through my app and when I try to enter the url directly.

Comment: Check your bucket policy and CORS configuration. Can you add a link to an asset in your bucket so I can see how s3 responds?

Comment: I'm checking out the bucket policy and cors file now but having a hard time figuring it out.  Working in now.  I can't figure out how to add 'Everyone' to the principles for the new bucket policy.  Asset:https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/haggard/aRush134.jpg

Comment: I added a link to sample bucket policies. To view your policy select your bucket and view properties.

Comment: If you dont want to user CarrierWave or Paperclip, check out Fog. your underlying problem here is that you need to add "Everyone READ" permissions to your bucket. Easiest way? use CyberDuck, connect, and add permissions to your bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to everyone that worked with me on this problem, especially @LarryMcKenzie.  The problem is that you need to set file permissions on upload and there is no way to mass assign permissions to all objects in a bucket.

Solution:  I reuploaded all of the images with the Open/Download flag set to true for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the paperclip gem for image uploading. I know it doesn't seem necessary, but when it comes to allowing users to upload to disk, it's better to leave it to the professionals. (Why re-invent the wheel?).

With paperclip, you can do things like

```
User.profile_pic.url
```

or

```
User.images.first.image.url
```

I certainly think it's the way to go.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I'll consider doing that in the future.  However heroku recommends against using that method.

Comment: Heroku absolutely recommends using paperclip.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip is great solution for uploading and serving files but it sounds like you have already uploaded all of the content you intend to serve. This is a permissions issue with your S3 bucket.
Amazon Sample bucket policies:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html