# On Amazon S3 I'm able to give an individual object download rights but cannot for the entire bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've got images on S3 that I'd like to share with my Rails app.  I can get access to the images by setting the permission: `Everybody - Open/Download` on the S3 UI.  I want to set this permission for all objects in the bucket. The bucket permission UI doesn't have the option of `Open/Download` for users. What is the `action` I need to assign in the bucket config command to allow this?  Here is my current command:

```
{


"Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "anid",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ansid",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::haggard/akey"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: afaik this needs to be set immediately on file upload or otherwise later per file. There is no "directory default" or "bucket default". We're syncing the S3 with http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/ and doing it on a "filesystem level".

Comment: I see @AxelAmthor, pain in the butt but a lesson learned.  Thank you.

Comment: @AxelAmthor, I just wiped my bucket and I'm reuploading with the appropriate permissions set.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoeEssey, Have tried S3 bucket policy? It sets rights for all the objects contained in the bucket and it is applicable to bucket.

Comment: @RuchitRami, Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately none of the bucket policies correspond to viewing individual files.  See the first comment by Axel Amthor.

Answer (score 0):

Your policy is probably wrong, this one is working fine for Everyone (Anonymous) users:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1416915063227",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AddCannedAcl",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I recommend to use the policy generator at the following link:
http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html